# Filename.tar.gz file download in Jmeter issue

Tags: performance, jmeter, zip, gzip, load-testing

I need to download a zipfile in the .tar.gz format from Amazon S3. When I use chrome to download I am getting the correct format. But with jmeter "Save Responses to a file" listener I am getting in .x-gzip format.

As I need to download 1000 unique files it is not possible to manually extract. So, I want to automate the extraction as well. Could you please help me to get the zip file in .tar.gz in jmeter or any converter available for batch run?

Chrome download: Filename.tar.gz (Correct one)
Jmeter download: Filename.x-gzip (Incorrect one)

Answer (score 0):

If the extension is the only issue with your test - just tick `Don't add content type suffix` box in the Save Responses to a file listener:

[image]

This way JMeter won't append [content-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) of the response to the filename

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)

Comment: Tried checking "Don't add content type suffix". There is no extension. But I want the file to be in .gz or zip format. Manually renaming it didn't solve the issue.